# A to Z List of Custom Post Type in three columns

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, list

I want to display custom post types A to Z Index in three columns, but it just lists the first post under each alphabet in three columns, I think there is some issue with the loop but can not figure out how can I fix it

The  code is listed below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="serviceproviders-inner-content haslayout">
<h2>A to Z Medication Guide </h2>
<?php

$query = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'post_type'     => 'medicines',
                        'orderby'       => 'title',
                        'order'         => 'ASC',
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1
                        ));

$post_count = $query->post_count;
$posts_per_column = ceil($post_count / 4);      

$rows = array();                                            
$count = 0;

while ($query->have_posts())

{ 
    $query->the_post(); 

    if($rows[$count] == "" ) { $rows[$count] = '<div class="row">'; }




        If ($letter != strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]))
        {
                // echo ($letter != '') ? '</ul></div>' : '';
                 $letter = strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]);  

        $rows[$count] = $rows[$count] .  '<div class="col-sm-3">' .  '<h4>'.strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]).'</h4>' .'<div class="post-title">'. '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>' . '</div></div>';  
        $count++;                           

        }   

        if ($count == $posts_per_column ) { $count = 0; } 


}
foreach ($rows as $row) { echo $row . '</div>'; }
?>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line:

```
$rows[$count] = $rows[$count] .  '<div class="col-sm-3">' .  '<h4>'.strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]).'</h4>' .'<div class="post-title">'. '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>' . '</div></div>';
```

As I understand your code correctly, it should append another column item to given row.

But it doesn't do it - it overwrites the content of given row with current column.

So it should look like this (`.=` instead of `=`):

```
$rows[$count] .= $rows[$count] .  '<div class="col-sm-3">' .  '<h4>'.strtoupper(get_the_title()[0]).'</h4>' .'<div class="post-title">'. '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>' . '</div></div>';
```

PS. You wrote that you want 3 columns, but in your code you divide by 4 - but maybe that's just a typo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code It displays the same value in the second row as well.